# how to prevent automatic shift in decimal numbers in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scientific-notation

Here is my code:

```
y = np.array([-3.44 , 1.16 , -0.81])
y = np.exp(y)
print(y)
```

for this block, I got the below result

```
[0.03206469 3.18993328 0.44485807]
```

**However, when I add `3.91` to the list, the result changed**

```
x = np.array([-3.44 , 1.16 , -0.81 , 3.91])
x = np.exp(x)
print(x)
```

result:

```
[3.20646853e-02 3.18993328e+00 4.44858066e-01 4.98989520e+01]
```

how can I prevent this change?

Comment: That's a change in display format, not a change in values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.set_printoptions`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html):

```
>>> x = np.array([-3.44 , 1.16 , -0.81 , 3.91])
>>> x = np.exp(x)
>>> print(x)
[3.20646853e-02 3.18993328e+00 4.44858066e-01 4.98989520e+01]

>>> np.set_printoptions(suppress=True, precision=8)

>>> print(x)
[ 0.03206469  3.18993328  0.44485807 49.89895197]
```

**Explanation:**

Decimal rounding can not always be exactly represented in binary, so you will see some floating point inconsistencies. For example:

```
>>> 0.1 + 0.2
0.30000000000000004
```

In light of these inconsistencies, `numpy` by default represents floating points in scientific notation. The way I have shown above, only sets the printing option to the way you desire, but the actual representation inside the array does not change.

`np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)` suppresses the scientific notation, and suppresses the floating points to `8` decimal places by default, so technically the `precision` parameter was not needed in this case:

```
>>> np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
>>> x
[ 0.03206469  3.18993328  0.44485807 49.89895197]
```

I added `precision` just in case you want a desired precision while printing.

```
>>> np.set_printoptions(suppress=True, precision=2)
>>> x
array([ 0.03,  3.19,  0.44, 49.9 ])
```

Learn more about floating point operations here:

1. [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588014/5431791)
2. https://0.30000000000000004.com/

Comment: thanks, would you mind explaining the concept of this problem, please?

Comment: @alifallahi added.